# redirection to codeigniter with Hebrew characters

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

I have created .htaccess file which redirects users who enter `www.example.com/he/שם-העמוד` to `www.2016.example.com/he/שם-העמוד`

Redirection itself work as expected, but I keep getting 404 error, altough the adress is correct (if I refresh after I was redirected to `www.2016.example.com/he/שם-העמוד`, it works).

.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.2016.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Worth mentioning:

- when using enlish characters, e.g `www.example.com/en/page-name`, it works perfectly
- Redirection leads to codeigniter installation

any idea what goes wrong?

Comment: Have you cleared your cache? If it works after refreshing the same page (after redirect) then it sounds like your cache might be messing it up.

Comment: I did clear browser's cache and checked on multiple browsers

Comment: Can you access `www.2016.example.com/index.php/he/שם-העמוד`?

Comment: yes, when I enter this url directly it's accessible